# DynamoDB selecting by date GSI write units

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently creating a dynamodb table where the primary key is a userId to ensure uniqueness. However I have a need to select back rows based on a timestamp where I won't know the userID and there will be multiple user ids returned. For instance (pseduo select)

`select * from table where dateCreated was yesterday`

So for this I was going to create a GSI of dateCreated.

Should dateCreated also be a sort key on the primary key or is it fine as a GSI on it's own?

Secondly once I have retrieved these items I will most likely want to update them, but if I specify that the GSI should return all attributes, do I actually need to assign any write units to the GSI? As if I return all attributes I should have the userID, so in theory I could use the userID to then do my write operations?

In this respect with regards to the free tier, could I in theory set up my PrimaryKey with all 25 write units and then set-up my GSI with all 25 of the free read units? ( I think it might actually force you to at least enter '1' but you get the idea)

Should my GSI also have a sort key defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to set `dateCreated` as a sort key on the table in order for it to be the hash key on your `DateCreatedGSI`. Set it as the sort key only if you plan on querying the table on `userId` and wish to have all the results sorted by `dateCreated`.

With respect to your questions about read/write throughput, you need to understand that although "provisioned throughput settings of a global secondary index are separate from those of its base table", writes are connected. "A Query operation on a global secondary index consumes read capacity units from the index, not the base table. When you put, update or delete items in a table, the global secondary indexes on that table are also updated; these index updates consume write capacity units from the index, not from the base table." So, yes, you do need to assign write capacity to the GSI, in addition to read capacity. See the docs for more detail: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.ThroughputConsiderations. Per this doc, if you don't have enough write capacity set on your GSI, the whole update to the table can be rejected: "In order for a table write to succeed, the provisioned throughput settings for the table and all of its global secondary indexes must have enough write capacity to accommodate the write; otherwise, the write to the table will be throttled."

Finally, as in the case of your main table, you should define a sort key on your GSI only if you care about the way your results are sorted when they are returned to you.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I would need to split the write and read capacity between the primary index and the GSI, even if I only 'read' or queried the GSI but updated using the primary key?

Comment: Yes, because DynamoDB keeps the table and GSI data in sync, so a write to the table also does a write to the GSI. I edited my answer above to include detail about what happens if you don't have enough write capacity set on your GSI, namely, your table update will get rejected. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just to clarify one more thing (sorry) I am able to split up the read units though? Even though my GSI returns the PK, it's reading objects based off the GSI which happens to contain all the attributes including the PK? Or because it's accessing the PK do I still need read units associated with it? (I know I have to have at least 1 read unit though by default)

Comment: I think maybe you have a typo in your question? Are you asking about the need for read capacity on your table? DynamoDB consumes write capacity from your GSI to copy changes made to the table to your GSI. With the understanding that GSIs are in sync with the table, "A Query operation on a global secondary index consumes read capacity units from the index, not the base table."

Comment: So, as long as you project all the attributes you need, you won't be reading from the table at all, so minimize the read capacity you assign to the table and use it on the GSI that you'll be querying. Info about attribute projections here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Projections

Comment: Note: This is different for Local Secondary Indexes. In this case, you project attributes, but if you ask for additional ones in your query, DynamoDB will fetch them from the main table, consuming read capacity on your LSI and your table.

Answer (score 1):

1. `dateCreated` need not be a sort key on the main table
2. Yes, ReadCapacityUnits and WriteCapacityUnits should be defined for
   GSI as well. This is required for the replication of data from main
   table to GSI
3. I am not sure about the write operation that you would like to
   perform using userId. DynamoDB will automatically populate the data
   from main table onto GSI. You can't write anything directly to the
   GSI. However, you can read directly from GSI
4. No, sort key is not mandatory on GSI